# Unity3d Facebook Response Data parsing

Tags: json, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

**I was able to solve this solution is in the coment**

I have problem with parsing data that I get rom Facebook on appRequestCallback.

The request is send and that part is ok. But I need to pars the send data for the internal uses.

the code is this

```
private void appRequestCallback(FBResult result)
{
    Util.Log("appRequestCallback");
    if (result != null)
    {
        var responseObject = Json.Deserialize(result.Text) as Dictionary<string, object>;
        object obj = 0;
        string resp = (string)responseObject["request"];
        Util.Log ("resp : " + resp);
        if (responseObject.TryGetValue("cancelled", out obj))
        {
            Util.Log("Request cancelled");
        }
        else if (responseObject.TryGetValue("request", out obj))
        {

            responseObject.TryGetValue("to", out obj);
            string[] s = (string[]) obj;
            Util.Log ("s: " + s);

            AddPopupMessage("Request Sent", ChallengeDisplayTime);
            Util.Log("Request sent");
        }
    }
}
```

In the console I get this

appRequestCallback

UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)

resp: 870884436303337

UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)

And then the error

InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
MainMenu.appRequestCallback (.FBResult result) (at Assets/Resources/Scripts/MainMenu.cs:482)
Facebook.AsyncRequestDialogPost.CallbackWithErrorHandling (.FBResult result)
Facebook.AsyncRequestString+c__Iterator0.MoveNext ()

The problem is in parsing of to: part of json file and I am not sure why. I have tried to cast it into string, string[], List<>, Array, ArrayList. As I see the problem is that I am not using the good cast type for the to: but I can not figure out what the correct cast type is

Comment: Don't cast it, and then inspect it?

Comment: I was able to solve it with this

`List<object> p = (List<object>)(responseObject["to"]);
    foreach(string s in p)
    {
     Debug.Log("Number: " + s);

    }`

Comment: Why not now create a model that maps to the response, so you can just cast it?